# TSQL Append To Row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains account numbers and tags (key words). My query checks to see if that account exists and if it does, it needs to append the new keywords to what already exits.

If the account doesn't exit, it just does a simple insert.

My struggle is getting the current Tags from the IF Exists clause and appending the new data to in it in the update statement. Any ideas?

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT id, tags FROM AccountLogAccounts WHERE account = @account)
BEGIN
    UPDATE AccountLogAccounts 
    SET tags = (
        SELECT tags 
        FROM AccountLogAccounts
        WHERE account = @account
    ) + ',' @tags --This doesn't work :)
    WHERE account = @account
END
ELSE
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO AccountLogAccounts (
            account,
            location,
            tags,
            whoAdded,
            whenAdded
        ) VALUES (
            @account,
            @location,
            @tags,
            @ntid,
            GETDATE()
        )
            END
END
```

Comment: I need to get the result from the exist statement (the current tags) and append the new data to it in an update statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of...

```
UPDATE AccountLogAccounts 
    SET tags = (
        SELECT tags 
        FROM AccountLogAccounts
        WHERE account = @account
    ) + ',' @tags --This doesn't work :)
    WHERE account = @account
```

...try...

```
UPDATE AccountLogAccounts 
    SET tags = tags + ',' + @tags
    WHERE account = @account
```

**EDIT**

Here's a little demo (untested, but should work):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateMyText
    @account int,
    @tags nvarchar(max)
AS
UPDATE AccountLogAccounts 
    SET tags = CAST(tags as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + @tags
    WHERE account = @account
GO

EXEC UpdateMyText 12345, 'abc'
GO
```

Comment: "The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the add operator."

Comment: @SSB You need to stop using the `TEXT` datatype.  You should be using `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead, which does not have this problem.

Comment: Text (and ntext) have been deprecated, so you should replace them with varchar.  Meanwhile, just cast your text field as varchar.

Comment: Same issue with that one:
The data types varchar(max) and text are incompatible in the add operator.